# Как я могу сократить код?

Tags: python-3.x

```
if playing_field[0] == "X" and playing_field[1] == "X" and playing_field[2] == "X":
        print("Победил(а) -",name_User_1)
        open_close_game()

elif playing_field[3] == "X" and playing_field[4] == "X" and playing_field[5] == "X":
        print("Победил(а) -",name_User_1)
        open_close_game()

elif playing_field[6] == "X" and playing_field[7] == "X" and playing_field[8] == "X":
        print("Победил(а) -",name_User_1)
        open_close_game()
```

Comment: `if any(playing_field[i:i+3] == ['X', 'X', 'X'] for i in (0, 3, 6)):`

Comment: я Самоучка, примерно знаю все основы, но как пользоваться ими в полной мере не умею, с циклами For у меня всегда проблемы

Comment: А почему для крестиков-ноликов массив одномерный? Это максимально не логично.

Comment: Не знаю, я пытаюсь переделать мою бывшую игру в крестики нолики, она работает идеально, но стоит из 650 строк, так как 2 уровня сложности , когда играешь с ботом